# Is there a convenient way to prototype future structure of View layer of MVC framework (Rails or like) on pure HTML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, partial-views

My "Rails friends" have a situation when their UI designer is beginning his work on prototyping UI screens on his own - their Rails programmer is busy and is going to join this work later, probably much later.

I know, it is easy to ask UI designer the learn Rails rendering mechanism, so he could begin prototyping on Rails, but I am interested,

**is it possible to setup views structure using partials (reusable pieces of HTML views) using just pure HTML, without any ruby code inside?**

The only approach I see is to use [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). Are there any other options?

What is needed is simply a possibility for one html-file could have a string like

```
<whatever include other.html ...>
```

which would include the contents of other.html inside its body.

This way, a future project can be divided logically on changeable/nonchangeable parts without any Ruby/Php code for partials.

**UPDATE 1**

The quoted wiki page about SSI has Client Side Includes section that suggests using object tag which seems to work

```
<object type="text/html" data="test.html"></object>
```

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is to use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com), which is a simple and quick web framework for static sites.

It's easy to start using Sinatra even for a beginner. However, even if the UI man doesn't know and don't want to study any coding, he can still utilize it by planning the partial names and ask the developer to setup it for him. All he need to do later is to fill each blank templates and add JS CSS image assets.

Benefit of Sinatra:

- Friendly to static sites
- Simple to use
- Lots of templating language to use, same as Rails
- The partials/templates can be ported to Rails later with zero efforts!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know Sinatra and I know it is an option. But I am trying to concentrate on pure HTML in this question.

Comment: @Stanislaw, I see your point. The main problem of using pure HTML is the lack of partial. One option is PHP but Sinatra is apparently better.